# I want to store Image album in Firebase database and storage

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store image as first collection name and document name as album name and then image name with path. I have stored images, but not like that as I wanted. I can't create another collection without document:

I want to create this

[image]

```
 btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (edtTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter Title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

  final String gelleryId =FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().
  collection("Gallery").document(edtTitle.getText().toString()).getId();              

            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();
            for(int i =0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
                StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
                final StorageReference patientiamge = mStorageRef.child("Gallery").child(gelleryId).child(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                patientiamge.putFile(arrayList.get(i))
                        .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                            if (taskSnapshot.getTask().isComplete()) {
                                patientiamge.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                                    final String imageid = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Gallery").document().getId();

                                    GelleryListModel gelleryListModel = new GelleryListModel();
                                    gelleryListModel.setId(imageid);
                                    gelleryListModel.setAlbumName(edtTitle.getText().toString());
                                    gelleryListModel.setImagePath(uri.toString());
                                    gelleryListModel.setBranchId(String.valueOf(branchId));
                                    Log.e("@@ImageId", imageid);
                                    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Gallery").document("").collection(edtTitle.getText().toString()).document().set(gelleryListModel).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                            finish();

                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
                        });
            }
```

I want to create like first Collection name than album name and then image path. I have no idea how to do it and I dont know it is possible or not. I have got all entries but not as I wanted.

Comment: What in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Please write short and clear sentences explaining your issue. Your text is really confusing. Tried to fix it by removing parts that were not full statements and the fluff

Answer (score 1):

Using the album name as the ID of the document in your `Gallery` collection is easy:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Gallery").document(edtTitle.getText());
```

I recommend against using the user input for the subcollection name however. There is no client-side API to get a list of (sub)collections, so it's best to use collection names that are in your code.

I'm not sure what purpose that subcollection serves, but if it has an identifiable purpose, you'd typically name the collection after that purpose (e.g. `image_ids`) and then name the documents with the dynamic value you had in mind.